# IBMQ import error

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience

I am trying to import IBMQ from qiskit. But I encountered following error.

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 1
----> 1 from qiskit import IBMQ

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qiskit\__init__.py:38
     36     _suppress_error = os.environ.get("QISKIT_SUPPRESS_1_0_IMPORT_ERROR", False) == "1"
     37     if int(_major) > 0 and not _suppress_error:
---> 38         raise ImportError(
     39             "Qiskit is installed in an invalid environment that has both Qiskit >=1.0"
     40             " and an earlier version."
     41             " You should create a new virtual environment, and ensure that you do not mix"
     42             " dependencies between Qiskit <1.0 and >=1.0."
     43             " Any packages that depend on 'qiskit-terra' are not compatible with Qiskit 1.0 and"
     44             " will need to be updated."
     45             " Qiskit unfortunately cannot enforce this requirement during environment resolution."
     46             " See https://qisk.it/packaging-1-0 for more detail."
     47         )
ImportError: Qiskit is installed in an invalid environment that has both Qiskit >=1.0 and an earlier version. You should create a new virtual environment, and ensure that you do not mix dependencies between Qiskit <1.0 and >=1.0. Any packages that depend on 'qiskit-terra' are not compatible with Qiskit 1.0 and will need to be updated. Qiskit unfortunately cannot enforce this requirement during environment resolution. See https://qisk.it/packaging-1-0 for more detail.
```

I also run `pip install qiskit-ibmq-provider`.
Can you please help to solve this error?

Answer (score 2):

Qiskit was updated to 1.0.0 version in February 2024, and this 1.0.0 version is not backward compatible (meaning many API and the way qiskit is packaged has been changed). And because the version 1.0.0 is not backward compatible you cannot do `pip install -U qiskit` or you should not install `qiskit 1.0.0` with any previous qiskit versions (<0.46).

The error that you are getting means that you have installed `qiskit 1.0.0` with a previous version on the same PC without using virtual environments. I would suggest you should make a virtual environment and then install `qiskit 1.0.0` in it. By doing so you can use older qiskit versions alongwith the new `1.0.0` version.

Follow the "For users" section in this link and you will find how to install and setup `qiskit 1.0.0` with any older qiskit version.
https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/api/migration-guides/qiskit-1.0-installation#for-users

Answer (score 1):

Since qiskit has been updates to Qiskit 1.0, but some of their versions like Qiskit terra doesn't support it. I suggest you make a virtual environment and install qiskit 0.45 in that.
That'll clear the error.

You can follow this to do this
https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/start/install

But instead of simple pip install qiskit
Do pip install qiskit==0.45.0

Or any version less than 1.0

Comment: Alternatively can update the code to work with Qiskit 1.0. This involves not using the obsolete IBMQ provider (replaced by qiskit-ibm-runtime).